# Difference between SoftIRQs and Tasklets

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, softirq, tasklet

While studying Linux interrupt handling I found that Tasklets and SoftIRQs are two different methods of performing "bottom half" (lesser priority work). I understand this (quite genuine need).

Difference being, SoftIRQs are re-entarant while a Tasklet is NOT. That same SoftIRQ can run on different CPUs while this is NOT the case with Tasklets.

Though I understand this from surface but I fail in understanding the requirements of the two features. In what case(s) we may use these facilities ? How to recognize that I should use Tasklets now and SoftIRQs then.

Also what do we mean by Tasklets are made upon SoftIRQs ? In one of the books I read in LKML there were debates upon removing Tasklets. I got completely confused why one would bring in such a feature ? Some shortsightedness (No offense meant) ?

Any pointers on this will help a lot.

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/240085/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[include/linux/interrupt.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/interrupt.h?id=v4.2-rc4#n400)

```
/* PLEASE, avoid to allocate new softirqs, if you need not _really_ high
   frequency threaded job scheduling. For almost all the purposes
   tasklets are more than enough. F.e. all serial device BHs et
   al. should be converted to tasklets, not to softirqs.
 */

enum
{
        HI_SOFTIRQ=0,    /* High Priority */
        TIMER_SOFTIRQ,
        NET_TX_SOFTIRQ,
        NET_RX_SOFTIRQ,
        BLOCK_SOFTIRQ,
        BLOCK_IOPOLL_SOFTIRQ,
        TASKLET_SOFTIRQ,
        SCHED_SOFTIRQ,
        HRTIMER_SOFTIRQ,
        RCU_SOFTIRQ,    /* Preferable RCU should always be the last softirq */

        NR_SOFTIRQS
};
```

The key differences between `softirq` and `tasklet` are:

> Allocation

- Softirqs are statically allocated at compile-time. Unlike tasklets, you cannot dynamically register and destroy softirqs.
- Tasklets can be statically allocated using `DECLARE_TASKLET(name, func, data)` or can also be allocated dynamically and initialized at runtime using `tasklet_init(name, func, data)`

> Concurrency

- Softirqs can run concurrently on several CPUs, even if they are of the same type because softirqs are `reentrant` functions and must explicitly protect their data structures with spinlocks.
- Tasklets are `non-reentrant` and tasklets of the same type are always serialized: in other words, the same type of tasklet cannot be executed by two CPUs at the same time. However, tasklets of different types can be executed concurrently on several CPUs.

> Processing

- Softirqs are activated by means of the `raise_softirq()`. The pending softirqs are processed by `do_softirq()` and `ksoftirqd` kernel thread after being enabled by `local_bh_enable()` or by `spin_unlock_bh()`
- Tasklets are a bottom-half mechanism built on top of softirqs i.e. tasklets are represented by two softirqs: `HI_SOFTIRQ` and `TASKLET_SOFTIRQ`. Tasklets are actually run from a softirq. The only real difference in these types is that the `HI_SOFTIRQ` based tasklets run prior to the `TASKLET_SOFTIRQ` tasklets. So, `tasklet_schedule()` basically calls `raise_softirq(TASKLET_SOFTIRQ)`
- Note that softirqs (and hence tasklets and timers) are run on return from hardware interrupts, or on return from a system call. Also as soon as the thread that raised the softirq ends, that single softirq (and on other) is run to minimize `softirq latency`.

Answer (score 11):

Sofirqs are re-entrant , that is the different CPU can take the same softirq and execute it while the Tasklets are serialized that is the same CPU which is running the tasklet has the right to complete it , no other CPU can take it(in case of scheduling).
refer this [excellent](http://wiki.kldp.org/wiki.php/SoftIrqsAndTasklets) article.

Also you can enable/disable the defer processing by using the local_bh_enable() on the local CPU which actually makes the _ _local_bh_count non zero.

Also [read this book](https://github.com/shihyu/linux_kernel_driver/blob/master/Books/Essential%20Linux%20Device%20Drivers.pdf) (free downloadable)  Page number 131 - which explains the difference as well as explaination using the code example with a fake/dummy device - roller.

Comment: Hello @Raul, I know this answer was posted a long time ago. But now, the link to the book you referenced is no longer reachable. Would you be able to recall what book you were talking about about? post its name and may be update the reference? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Softirqs are statically allocated at compile- time. Unlike tasklets, you cannot dynamically register and destroy softirqs.Tasklets are similar to softirqs (working) however, they have a simpler interface.
Softirqs are required only for very high frequency and highly threaded uses , whereas , tasklets do just fine in any other case.

Answer (score 1):

Tasklets are implemented on top of softirq's, so they are softirq's. they are represented by two softirq's "HI_SOFTIRQ & TASKLET_SOFTIRQ" difference is priority.
Even though they are implemented on top of softirq's they differ in:

- Tasklets can be created/destroyed statically or dynamically but softirq's are only by static way.
- Two different tasklets can run concurrently on same cpu. But two of the same type of tasklets can not run on same cpu. Whereas softirq's are in the other way.

Softirq's are reserved  for most time critical & important bottom half processing on system.